# What is best way to represent polymorphic associations in relational database?

Tags: relational-database, polymorphic-associations

Assuming this representation of the tables :

[image: db parent/child tables]

Object is the "parent" table that holds the objectids of all the other 4 child tables .
The 'something' table , besides having an objectid column , will also include linked_to_objectid column. This column points only to the objectid from object1 and object2 (not from object3) .

My problem is that i will have to check everytime when i insert a row , if the linked_to_objectid is not from object3 .

Another way would be to add another column to object table that would describe what type of object the objectid is ... But it i feel that this would be wrong .

I know this model breaks the normal form rules , but i can't find some other ways .
Anyone could help me and find the best way to model this ?

Answer (score 4):

I think your answer is to use reciprocal primary/foreign keys and partition part of the primary key among your tables, something like:

```
 CREATE TABLE object_class (
     id int not null unique, -- hand assigned
     label text not null primary key
 );

 CREATE TABLE object (
     object_id bigserial not null primary key,
     class_id int not null references object_class(id),
     ...., 
     UNIQUE (object_id, class_id)
 );

 CREATE TABLE object1 (
      object_id bigint not null,
      class_id bigint not null,
      .....
      check(class_id = 1),
      primary key (object_id, class_id),
      foreign key (object_id, class_id) references object(object_id, class_id)
 );

 etc.
```

Now if you are using PostgreSQL, you can probably use table inheritance and constraint triggers to implement something a bit cleaner, but that's relatively advanced stuff.

Comment: It's a nightmere to add triggers to keep the db integrity . It's simply a nightmere to implement oo concepts in rdbms. It can be done but not efficient . I don't like storing metadata about tables in another table (like your object class) . Anyway i kept it simple , only object super table wich stores all ids for all tables records. Droped all triggers (too many hand made contraints on delete/update/insert ) . Made some extra association tables in case i need some backward record handling . Anyway the best solution would be an oodb :) .

Comment: P.S. +1 your answer is good but can't accept it because the question can be answered in many ways depending some1's needs . And a complete answer wouldnt be too efficient. Many maybe would say go oodb way. :)

Comment: @TudorTudor Meh, it was only a decade ago that PostgreSQL got declarative referential integrity.  I do a fair bit of triggers to ensure RI and it isn't that bad.  DRI gets you most of the way there in any case.

Comment: Also note that many databases allow for deferrable foreign key constraints, making this even easier.  If the foreign key goes both ways, you can break out the column to a trigger maintained set of them, and add appropriate check constraints and deferrable foreign keys.

Comment: Again PostgreSQL's inheritance if you do referential integrity triggers, makes the problem quite a bit simpler, actually.

Comment: I wasn't really refering to referential integrity . Many rdbms offer support for key constraints (for db integrity). I was refering more to the data corectness. In rdmbs having a super table storing all ids of all tables would require some table type chcking later because each child table can have only a set of ids from parent table. I don't think any of the rdbms have support for some kind of table type constraints . The design could leade to composite+inheritance , not only inheritance . Thats why oodbms are better for this sort of things.